# Unity: Alpha and color issues with opaque projector/decal shader

Tags: unity, shaders, graphics, hlsl, graphics-programming

I have been attempting to make a simple "overwrite" version of Unity's projector shader.  I can either respect the color, or respect the transparency, but not both.

I have simplified the frag method to simply take cookie (the texture of the projection) and color tint, skipping all the fall off and fog stuff for now.  I hope to eventually add those back in once I figure out what's going wrong.

```
Shader "Projector/Overwrite" {
    Properties {
        _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _ShadowTex ("Cookie", 2D) = "" {}
        _FalloffTex ("FallOff", 2D) = "" {}
    }
    
    Subshader {
        Tags {"Queue"="Transparent"}
        Pass {
            ZWrite Off
            ColorMask RGB
            Blend DstColor DstAlpha
            //Blend DstColor Zero
            Offset -1, -1
    
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma multi_compile_fog
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"
            
            struct v2f {
                float4 uvShadow : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 uvFalloff : TEXCOORD1;
                UNITY_FOG_COORDS(2)
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            };
            
            float4x4 unity_Projector;
            float4x4 unity_ProjectorClip;
            
            v2f vert (float4 vertex : POSITION)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(vertex);
                o.uvShadow = mul (unity_Projector, vertex);
                o.uvFalloff = mul (unity_ProjectorClip, vertex);
                UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.pos);
                return o;
            }
            
            fixed4 _Color;
            sampler2D _ShadowTex;
            sampler2D _FalloffTex;
            
            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 texS = tex2Dproj (_ShadowTex, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(i.uvShadow));
                texS.rgb *= _Color.rgb;
                //texS.a = 1.0 - texS.a;
                return texS;

                /*texS.rgb *= _Color.rgb;
                texS.a = 1.0-texS.a;
    
                fixed4 texF = tex2Dproj (_FalloffTex, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(i.uvFalloff));
                fixed4 res = texS * texF.a;

                UNITY_APPLY_FOG_COLOR(i.fogCoord, res, fixed4(0,0,0,0));
                return res;*/
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

I am fairly certain the issue lies in the BLEND options.  I can either respect the texture * color, or respect the alpha of the texture, but not both together.

Alpha is respected, but the color is no longer accurate:
[image: Alpha is respected, but the color is no longer accurate]

Alpha is ignored, but the color is accurate:
[image: Alpha is ignored]

Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to use a multiplicative blend mode, where we tint the colour already drawn into the scene. We'll likely want to add a second pair of arguments to leave the destination alpha untouched:

```
Blend DstColor Zero, Zero One
```

Then you want to take the colour you're about to write, and blend it toward white where the alpha is low. Zero alpha means you're outputting white, which multiplied by any other colour, just produces that same colour, unchanged.

```
fixed4 texS = tex2Dproj (_ShadowTex, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(i.uvShadow));
texS.rgb *= _Color.rgb;
texS.rgb = lerp(fixed3(1, 1, 1), texS.rgb, texS.a);
return texS;
```

Or if you want standard alpha / layer blending, the formula for that is:

```
Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
```

And you can skip the `lerp`-to-white line.